# Have my input box reset after clicking anything but a number

Tags: javascript, input, reset

So im building a calculator.  The problem I have is that when I click a calculation sign AND THEN i input more numbers, the calculation sign appends to the front of the # of values.

How do I reset the input box so that once I click a number, the caluclation sign disappears and starts a new list of numbers - see some of my code below

```
if (!isNaN(e.target.textContent)) {
      inp.value += parseInt(e.target.textContent);
      val1 = inp.value;
      console.log(val1);
    } else if (
      isNaN(e.target.textContent) &&
      e.target.textContent !== "ENTER"
    ) {
      calculationSign = e.target.textContent;
      inp.value = e.target.textContent;
      console.log(calculationSign);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you could test if the input box is currently fed with an operator:

```
if (!isNaN(e.target.textContent)) {
    if (['+', '-', '*', '/'].indexOf(inp.value) !== -1) {
        inp.value = ''
    }
    inp.value += parseInt(e.target.textContent);
    val1 = inp.value;
    console.log(val1);
}
```

Anyway you'll need more state and logic to determine when the user inputs the second value, before triggering the computation with `ENTER`, but maybe it is elsewhere in your real code.

Comment: Is it possible to actually provide an explanation on what this code is saying?  I am trying to understand it  - is it saying if those signs do NOT match the inp.value then execute this code?

if (['+', '-', '*', '/'].indexOf(inp.value) !== -1)

Comment: `indexOf` returns the index of the given string (here `inp.value`) or `-1`if no match has been found. So this instruction means "if `inp.value` is one of these operators then...".